# Derivative of a Trigonometric Function with Cosine and Sine to find the Maximum

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives

The movement of the crest of a wave is modelled with the equation $h(t) = 0.2\cos(4t) + 0.3\sin(5t)$. Find the maximum height of the wave and the time at which it occurs.

*I have no idea how to go about solving for t. I understand that we need to find the derivative and set $h'(t) = 0$ however, when it comes to then solving for $t$, the sine and cosine in the relation make me unable to do so. Any help will be greatly appreciated*

Comment: solving h'(t)=0 is pretty hard, but you can get the answer to this question by simultaneously maximizing both the sin and cos terms. Find a value of t that satisfies $cos(4t)=1$ and $sin(5t)=1$

Answer (score 1):

Setting the derivative to zero leads to many solutions, some of them practically impossible to find analytically. Here is another solution, using only basic trigonometry.

The maximum possible value of $\cos(4t)$ is $1$, as is the maximum possible value of $\sin(5t)$. If we could get them both to get the value $1$ for the same value of $t$ that would definitely be the maximum.

We can see that letting $t=\frac{\pi}2$ does make both the cosine and the sine equal to $1$. Therefore, the maximum height of the wave is

$$0.2\cdot 1 + 0.3\cdot 1=0.5$$

and it happens at time $t=\frac{\pi}2$.

Some more checking will see that this is the only place the maximum occurs, up to a multiple of $2\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think u can use Newton's method. (I have tried it and i got $t \approx 1.035614\dots$)